# increment rows in TXT from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to convert this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="FPPD2.srdl" baseAmount_baseCreditAmount_TOTAL="1032.14" baseAmount_baseCreditAmount_COUNT="3" Today="2015-04-14T02:16:44" DocumentNumber="                41" ExecDate="2015-04-14">
   <Detail_2_1>
            <Detail_2_1_Group_Collection>
                <Item RowNumber="1" transactionDate="2004-04-01" accountCode_label_2="Account Code:" accountCode_3="PK181010" description_1="Telephone" paymentAccount_1="BANK" transactionReference="404TELE001NYC" description_label_2="Description:" description_2="Teleford communications" baseAmount_baseCreditAmount="428.57" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount_x="0.00" baseAmount_amount_1="428.57" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount="" baseAmount_amount_10="-428.57" supplierName_label_1="Supplier Name:" supplierName_1="Teleford &amp; Communications" addressLine1_label_1="Address Line 1:" addressLine1_1="57 Harpermoorish Ave" addressLine2_label_1="Address Line 2:" addressLine2_1="" addressLine3_label_1="Address Line 3:" addressLine3_1="" addressLine4_label_1="Address Line 4:" addressLine4_1="Birmingham  RG5 5BJ" addressLine5_label_1="Address Line 5:" addressLine5_1="UK" TownCity_label_1="Town/City:" TownCity_1="Birmingham" State_label_1="State:" State_1="" StateCode_label_1="State Code:" StateCode_1="" PostalCode_label_1="Postal Code:" PostalCode_1="RG5 5BJ" Country_label_1="Country:" Country_1="UK" document_1="Document:" TextBox_15="404TELE001NYC" bankAccountName_label_1="Bank Account Name:" bankAccountName_1="Travelbug Software Ltd" bankAccountNumber_label_1="Bank Account Number:" bankAccountNumber_1="DE21500500001234567897" BankSortCode_label_1="Bank Sort Code:" BankSortCode_1="BUINBGSF123" BankSubcode_label_1="Bank Subcode:" BankSubcode_1="" BankBranch_label_1="Bank Branch:" BankBranch_1="Southampton" BankDetailsCode_label_1="Bank Details Code:" BankDetailsCode_1="81010" BankName_label_1="Bank Name:" BankName_1="Midland Bank Plc" SwiftCode_label_1="Extension Swift Code:" SwiftCode_1="" />
                <Item RowNumber="2" transactionDate="2004-05-01" accountCode_label_2="Account Code:" accountCode_3="PK181010" description_1="Telephone" paymentAccount_1="BANK" transactionReference="405TELE001NYC" description_label_2="Description:" description_2="Teleford communications" baseAmount_baseCreditAmount="428.57" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount_x="0.00" baseAmount_amount_1="857.14" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount="" baseAmount_amount_10="-857.14" supplierName_label_1="Supplier Name:" supplierName_1="Teleford &amp; Communications" addressLine1_label_1="Address Line 1:" addressLine1_1="57 Harpermoorish Ave" addressLine2_label_1="Address Line 2:" addressLine2_1="" addressLine3_label_1="Address Line 3:" addressLine3_1="" addressLine4_label_1="Address Line 4:" addressLine4_1="Birmingham  RG5 5BJ" addressLine5_label_1="Address Line 5:" addressLine5_1="UK" TownCity_label_1="Town/City:" TownCity_1="Birmingham" State_label_1="State:" State_1="" StateCode_label_1="State Code:" StateCode_1="" PostalCode_label_1="Postal Code:" PostalCode_1="RG5 5BJ" Country_label_1="Country:" Country_1="UK" document_1="Document:" TextBox_15="405TELE001NYC" bankAccountName_label_1="Bank Account Name:" bankAccountName_1="Travelbug Software Ltd" bankAccountNumber_label_1="Bank Account Number:" bankAccountNumber_1="DE21500500001234567897" BankSortCode_label_1="Bank Sort Code:" BankSortCode_1="BUINBGSF123" BankSubcode_label_1="Bank Subcode:" BankSubcode_1="" BankBranch_label_1="Bank Branch:" BankBranch_1="Southampton" BankDetailsCode_label_1="Bank Details Code:" BankDetailsCode_1="81010" BankName_label_1="Bank Name:" BankName_1="Midland Bank Plc" SwiftCode_label_1="Extension Swift Code:" SwiftCode_1="" />
                <Item RowNumber="3" transactionDate="2004-02-01" accountCode_label_2="Account Code:" accountCode_3="PK181015" description_1="Leased Lines" paymentAccount_1="BANK" transactionReference="402TELE003TOK" description_label_2="Description:" description_2="Integration International" baseAmount_baseCreditAmount="175.00" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount_x="0.00" baseAmount_amount_1="1,032.14" baseAmount_baseDebitAmount="" baseAmount_amount_10="-1,032.14" supplierName_label_1="Supplier Name:" supplierName_1="Integration International" addressLine1_label_1="Address Line 1:" addressLine1_1="49, Station Road" addressLine2_label_1="Address Line 2:" addressLine2_1="" addressLine3_label_1="Address Line 3:" addressLine3_1="" addressLine4_label_1="Address Line 4:" addressLine4_1="London  E4 7BJ" addressLine5_label_1="Address Line 5:" addressLine5_1="" TownCity_label_1="Town/City:" TownCity_1="London" State_label_1="State:" State_1="" StateCode_label_1="State Code:" StateCode_1="" PostalCode_label_1="Postal Code:" PostalCode_1="E4 7BJ" Country_label_1="Country:" Country_1="" document_1="Document:" TextBox_15="402TELE003TOK" bankAccountName_label_1="Bank Account Name:" bankAccountName_1="Creditor Account" bankAccountNumber_label_1="Bank Account Number:" bankAccountNumber_1="DE21500500009876543210" BankSortCode_label_1="Bank Sort Code:" BankSortCode_1="CRBABGSF" BankSubcode_label_1="Bank Subcode:" BankSubcode_1="" BankBranch_label_1="Bank Branch:" BankBranch_1="Cambridge" BankDetailsCode_label_1="Bank Details Code:" BankDetailsCode_1="81015" BankName_label_1="Bank Name:" BankName_1="Lloyds Bank" SwiftCode_label_1="Extension Swift Code:" SwiftCode_1="" />
            </Detail_2_1_Group_Collection>
        </Detail_2_1>
</Report>
```

into this txt file:

```
000001  HEADER
000002  404TELE001NYC
000003  Teleford communications
000004  57 Harpermoorish Ave
000005  405TELE001NYC
000006  Teleford communications
000007  57 Harpermoorish Ave
000008  402TELE003TOK
000009  Integration International
000010  49, Station Road
```

I only have issues with the incrementing number. If I use this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:ns2="FPPD2.srdl">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:variable name="some_spaces" select="'                                                '" />

<xsl:template match="/ns2:Report">
<xsl:text>000001    HEADER</xsl:text>
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ns2:Detail_2_1/ns2:Detail_2_1_Group_Collection/ns2:Item"/>                                                                                                                                          38415740000027VET</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns2:Item">
    <xsl:value-of select='format-number(position(), "000000")'/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@transactionReference"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="width" select="18"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='format-number(position(), "000000")'/>
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@description_2"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="width" select="18"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select='format-number(position(), "000000")'/>
    <xsl:call-template name="pad">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="@addressLine1_1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="width" select="18"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="pad">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="width" />
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($text, $some_spaces), 1, $width)"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get this (because the position() function looks at the items in the source XML and of course not in the target txt). So the purpose is to increment all rows on the txt file by 1. Items start from row 2 (first row is a header so I have hard-coded 000001).

```
000001  HEADER
000001  404TELE001NYC
000001  Teleford communications
000001  57 Harpermoorish Ave
000002  405TELE001NYC
000002  Teleford communications
000002  57 Harpermoorish Ave
000003  402TELE003TOK
000003  Integration International
000003  49, Station Road
```

Comment: Perhaps you can do something like `<xsl:value-of select='format-number(position() + #attno#, "000000")'/>`, where `attno` will be an offset value to be added, depending on the attribute you are currently processing (e.g. 0 for @Data1, 1 for @Data2, 2 for @Data3). This should be made by hand because I don't think you can "number" the attributes. Can you show us the XSLT you are using? Is the number of attribute fixed? Thanks.

Comment: `position()` is the position of the current node relative to the batch that you are processing. The surrounding `<xsl:apply-templates>` or `<xsl:for-each>` determines that. So you have to show more of your XSLT code.

Comment: Actually this is a very simplified example, I have tens of attributes in every XML item that I need to distribute among three rows (320 characters each) on the target TXT. My XSLT is quite big already so I didn't want to post the whole thing for the time being (unless there's no other way of course).

Comment: Will all the `Item` element have the same number of attributes, or can some be missing? If some can be missing, would you still expect a line in the text to be output?

Comment: Yes, all items have exactly the same attributes.

Comment: Yes, all items have exactly the same attributes, but not all of them are needed and from the ones that are needed some are on the same line, so not all of them produce a separate line.

Comment: For more insight I added an extended xslt as requested by several users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this can work for you:

```
<xsl:template match="ns1:Item">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:for-each select="@Data1 | @Data2 | @Data3">
        <xsl:value-of select="3 * ($i - 1) + position()"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFy/4 this is where I tried to use it, lines 27 to 32, but there's an error :

Comment: Thanks Michael, I used a piece of your code and it worked! <xsl:value-of select='format-number(2+3*(position()-1), "000000")'/> on the first line, <xsl:value-of select='format-number(3+3*(position()-1), "000000")'/>  on the second line and <xsl:value-of select='format-number(4+3*(position()-1), "000000")'/>  on the third line.